# Radius of convergence of a power series (little question about power + constant)

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

My power series are: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{x^{3n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}$$

So its isnt difficult if it was written without the $+1$ in the power: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}$$

Then its easy to see that the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{e}}$.

But how do I handle with any constants that I sum to it ? Does it implies somehow on the radius of convergence, and if it does, what is the implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum a_nx^{3n+1}$ converges if and only if $\sum a_nx^{3n}$ converges.

Comment: Really ? and if it was minus 2 ? Seems to be you do that conclusion by direct convergence test, maybe ? 
Or how you decided that ? Can you extent your explanation a little bit please ? Because formally we did saw this kind of exercises in class, but nobody mentioned or pay any additional attention to the power so I always just find the radius of convergence for rounded power, no matter what constant there was (minus or plus).

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{n=1}^N a_nx^{3n+1} = x\sum_{n=1}^N a_nx^{3n}$ so if $\sum a_nx^{3n}$ converges, then so does $\sum a_nx^{3n+1}$. The reverse is also true for $x\neq 0$, and for $x=0$, it is obvious.

Comment: $\sum a_nx^{3n-2}$ might not be defined if $a_0\neq 0$, but otherwise, it is still true.

Comment: Ok, I got it. And its true for any constant plus or minus as long as the series defined. I guess that the only kind of exercises i will get. Thanks.